# pasar datos a una jsp desde una clase java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de una consulta a una jsp? Me explico:

Tengo una página jsp de la cual obtengo parámetros, los paso a un servlet, este a su vez ejecuta una clase consulta que va a la bd, pero no sé cómo pasar el resultado de esa consulta a la misma jsp.

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres enviar datos desde el Servlet hacia la vista, puedes utilizar forward desde el servlet hacia tu JSP y agregar toda la información que necesites mostrar como atributos del request, luego en el JSP puedes acceder a estos atributos sin problemas.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
@WebServlet("busqueda.jsp")
public class BusquedaServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        //realizas la búsqueda aquí...
        List<Resultado> resultados = ... //lista con los resultados de la búsqueda
        //colocamos los resultados de la búsqueda como atributo del request
        request.setAttribute("resultados", resultados);
        //realizamos un forward a la página JSP donde mostraremos los resultados
        request.getRequestDispatcher("busqueda.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

JSP, el archivo busqueda.jsp (utilizo JSTL, recomendado para evitar usar scriptlets en tu código JSP):

```xhtml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Resultado de búsqueda</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
            </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${resultados}" var="resultado">
            <tr>
                <td>${resultado.id}</td>
                <td>${resultado.descripcion}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Se asume que la clase `Resultado` tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
public class Resultado {
    private int id;
    private String descripcion;

    //getters y setters para los campos de arriba
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes que submitar el formulario todavía (cosa que puedes hacer con un boton submit + request POST), puedes hacer una llamada ajax que se comunique con tu servidor sin necesidad de recargar toda la página.

```
$.get( "/ruta/metodoMapeado", function() {
  alert( "llamando al host" );
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("la respuesta es: " + data);
}).fail(function(error) {
    alert("hemos tenido el error" + error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade un objeto map a la respuesta con el objeto resultado que quieres consultar en el jsp

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.put("objeto", ObjetoQueQuieresConsultarEnJSP);
return new ModelAndView(home, "model", model);
```

Luego consulta en el jsp de la siguiente forma:

```
<% Map model = (Map) request.getAttribute("model"); %>

<% Object objecto = model.ObjetoQueQuieresConsultarEnJSP %>
```

En la variable objeto ya tienes el ObjetoQueQuieresConsultarEnJSP y puedes trabajar con el normalmente

Comment: Esto funciona solo con un framework como Spring. La pregunta es sobre servlets netamente.